# Can you fix a background/line/border in draw.io that stretches when you go onto a new work area/page?

Tags: background, border, fixed, stretch, draw.io

I'm in the process of setting up a template in Draw.io but would like to set it up so the background/page border stays fixed when extending the size of the work area.

Is there any way to do this either in Draw.io or maybe through a plugin? Or if I create it as a background is there anyway to set the background to stretch to fit the work area?

It could be a shape (rectangle) or an image inserted.

[image: Page Border]

[image: Extending the page by adding more items]

[image: Border automatically extended?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible at the moment but feel free to add a feature request here: https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues (for diagrams.net online) and https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/issues (for desktop version)

Regards,